# Facebook and Medium Content Placeholder Style

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

Recently I've noticed that Facebook and Medium are using a lazy loading style. However, there're none of the jQuery or any other library I've found yet to achieve the same style.

Does anyone know how to achieve that or any familiar jQuery library that can do the same?

Here's the screenshot which I'm referring to:
[image: Facebook and Medium style content loading]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just found one at Codepen:

```css
 @-webkit-keyframes placeHolderShimmer {
   0% {
     background-position: -468px 0
   }
   100% {
     background-position: 468px 0
   }
 }
 
 @keyframes placeHolderShimmer {
   0% {
     background-position: -468px 0
   }
   100% {
     background-position: 468px 0
   }
 }
 
 .timeline-wrapper {
   background-color: #e9eaed;
   color: #141823;
   padding: 20px;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
 }
 
 .timeline-item {
   background: #fff;
   border: 1px solid;
   border-color: #e5e6e9 #dfe0e4 #d0d1d5;
   border-radius: 3px;
   padding: 12px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   max-width: 472px;
   min-height: 200px;
 }
 
 .animated-background {
   -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
   animation-duration: 1s;
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   -webkit-animation-name: placeHolderShimmer;
   animation-name: placeHolderShimmer;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
   animation-timing-function: linear;
   background: #f6f7f8;
   background: #eeeeee;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(8%, #eeeeee), color-stop(18%, #dddddd), color-stop(33%, #eeeeee));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #eeeeee 8%, #dddddd 18%, #eeeeee 33%);
   background: linear-gradient(to right, #eeeeee 8%, #dddddd 18%, #eeeeee 33%);
   -webkit-background-size: 800px 104px;
   background-size: 800px 104px;
   height: 96px;
   position: relative;
 }
 
 .background-masker {
   background: #fff;
   position: absolute;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 
 .outlined .background-masker {
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
 }
 
 .outlined:hover .background-masker {
   border: none;
 }
 
 .outlined:hover .background-masker:hover {
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   z-index: 1;
 }
 
 .background-masker.header-top,
 .background-masker.header-bottom,
 .background-masker.subheader-bottom {
   top: 0;
   left: 40px;
   right: 0;
   height: 10px;
 }
 
 .background-masker.header-left,
 .background-masker.subheader-left,
 .background-masker.header-right,
 .background-masker.subheader-right {
   top: 10px;
   left: 40px;
   height: 8px;
   width: 10px;
 }
 
 .background-masker.header-bottom {
   top: 18px;
   height: 6px;
 }
 
 .background-masker.subheader-left,
 .background-masker.subheader-right {
   top: 24px;
   height: 6px;
 }
 
 .background-masker.header-right,
 .background-masker.subheader-right {
   width: auto;
   left: 300px;
   right: 0;
 }
 
 .background-masker.subheader-right {
   left: 230px;
 }
 
 .background-masker.subheader-bottom {
   top: 30px;
   height: 10px;
 }
 
 .background-masker.content-top,
 .background-masker.content-second-line,
 .background-masker.content-third-line,
 .background-masker.content-second-end,
 .background-masker.content-third-end,
 .background-masker.content-first-end {
   top: 40px;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   height: 6px;
 }
 
 .background-masker.content-top {
   height: 20px;
 }
 
 .background-masker.content-first-end,
 .background-masker.content-second-end,
 .background-masker.content-third-end {
   width: auto;
   left: 380px;
   right: 0;
   top: 60px;
   height: 8px;
 }
 
 .background-masker.content-second-line {
   top: 68px;
 }
 
 .background-masker.content-second-end {
   left: 420px;
   top: 74px;
 }
 
 .background-masker.content-third-line {
   top: 82px;
 }
 
 .background-masker.content-third-end {
   left: 300px;
   top: 88px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="timeline-wrapper">
  <div class="timeline-item">
    <div class="animated-background facebook">
      <div class="background-masker header-top"></div>
      <div class="background-masker header-left"></div>
      <div class="background-masker header-right"></div>
      <div class="background-masker header-bottom"></div>
      <div class="background-masker subheader-left"></div>
      <div class="background-masker subheader-right"></div>
      <div class="background-masker subheader-bottom"></div>
      <div class="background-masker content-top"></div>
      <div class="background-masker content-first-end"></div>
      <div class="background-masker content-second-line"></div>
      <div class="background-masker content-second-end"></div>
      <div class="background-masker content-third-line"></div>
      <div class="background-masker content-third-end"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```